# AJAX Response limit?

Tags: javascript, ajax, vb.net

Please see the code below:

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Function LinkedUSNs(ByVal usn As String, ByVal requester As String, ByVal reason As String, ByVal terminalip As String, ByVal strCon As String) As String
        Dim objUSNs As New clsUSNs(strCon)
        Dim objTable As Table = objUSNs.LinkedUSNs(CInt(usn), requester, CInt(reason), terminalip)
        Return getHTML(objTable)
    End Function
```

A HTML table is returned to an AJAX caller.  The code works as long as the table is not too big.  Once the table exceeds x rows then neither the onSuccess nor onFailure event handlers are called.

Why is this? Is there perhaps a restriction on the size of an AJAX response? Surely onFailure should be called in this case?

Comment: Does your browser respond when the ajax call is completed ??

Comment: @Manish Kr. shukla, no it does not.  It works as I would expect as long as the table has less than x rows.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with AJAX, its with thr browser.. The reason why you asked the question, is because i myself has invested a lot of time searching and working on this issue.

If you consider a normal 50 column table, with 5000 rows, your browser is expected to turn non-responsive receiving such huge response, or while rendering such table..

What i suggest you is to implement pagination, coz i myself i have done so.